# want the result as table should retrn all card type for one activity even though he has not done any particular cartype for that activity

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

i have table as employee_details.in employee_details  have column as emp_code,activity_id,card_id,quantity. the table look like:-

```
 #emp_code  activity_id  card_id      quantity
  001                    1            31           600
  002                    1            32           1200
```

the other table is:
activities table.in that table i have column as activity_id,activity.table look like

```
#activity_id     activity
     1            Lamination
     2            Tape laying
```

the other table is:
card_type table.in that table i have column as card_id,cardtype.table look like

```
#card_id           cardtype
     31            Barcoding
     32            Copper Patch
```

now i want the result as,when i am fetching the result for emp_code '001' it will show the activity 'Lamination' and cardtype 'Barcoding' as well as cardtype 'Copper Patch' for this employee even thought he has not done this cardtype on 'Lamination' activity. also it will show the quantity for  'Copper Patch' cardtype '0'.
the result should look like:-

```
emp_code     activity         cardtype       quantity
001          Lamination      Barcoding         600
001          Lamination     Copper Patch       0
002          Lamination     Copper Patch       1200
002          Lamination     Barcoding           0
```

please help to solve my query.

Comment: What happened to tape laying?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.emp_code,B.activity,C.cardtype,A.quantity
FROM employee_details as A 
JOIN activities as B ON A.activity_id = B.activity_id
JOIN card_type as C ON A.card_id = C.card_id;
```

Above is the mysql query for the requirement